# Minikube+Kubectl "Unable to connect to the server - timeout"

Tags: macos, deployment, kubernetes, kubectl, minikube

I'm studying the basic usage of Kubernetes through Minikube lightweight version installed in my Mac Pro Retina Mid 2015 processor i7.

I've noticed a strange behaviour: **It works perfectly in the first 1-2 minutes after I start the minikube**.
When about 2 minutes have passed, my kubelect goes always in **Timeout**  when it must get pods, services, deployments and when it interrogates directly the minikube.

For example it happens like this:

```
> minikube start
```

then I call:

```
> kubectl get pods
NAME                          READY     STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
aggregator-74d44fd6db-2vff5   0/1       Error     55         4d
aggregator-74d44fd6db-72bmw   0/1       Error     22         4d
chart-649cc6bfb-d8ksj         0/1       Error     17         4d
chart-649cc6bfb-vg6vr         0/1       Error     9          4d
frontend-8dbb85d74-87ltl      1/1       Running   6          4d
frontend-8dbb85d74-whwnk      1/1       Running   6          4d
user-79c94d5574-8vr2h         0/1       Error     10         4d
user-79c94d5574-x7x2d         0/1       Error     13         4d
```

after 2 minutes:

```
> kubectl get pods
No resources found.
Unable to connect to the server: net/http: TLS handshake timeout
```

To let it work again, I must stop and restart minikube and it comes to work just for another couple of minutes.
How is that possible?

Comment: Which minikube version are you running? Sometimes when it's updated, it is usefull to run `minikube delete` to delete all old cached files. Then next time you run `minikube start`, new files are downloaded. Give it a try

Comment: Hi Urosh, the version is v0.28.2. I've tried to delete all pods and deployments and now that is completely empty it doesn't block. But I still have to understand why. Thanks.

Comment: Just to make sure we are on the same page. `minikube delete` deletes ALL of minikube, not just pods and deployments. I usually have these problems when upgrading versions, etc. But unfortunately, can't explain why this happens, other than there are probably previous version files running on the new version and causing issues due to incompatibility.

Comment: Ok then, so your suggestion is just to delete minikube and recreate it, or updating/reinstalling the minikube version?

Comment: Are you sure that you have enough available resources provided for your minikube environment?

Comment: @AlexMawashi, just delete it and run it again using `minikube delete` then `minikube start`.

Comment: As I can experiment, when I create a particular deployment (2 replicas of a simple spring java app which connects with other two deployments through environment variables specified with dns name) my minikube gets always blocked. If I delete it it works fine. What can be wrong with this simple deployment?

Answer (score 1):

I would first try the delete and restart as suggested:
$ minikube delete
$ minikube start

Second, try giving more resources to minikube. THIS was a big help for me when running it and getting multiple pods going. I give have my memory and have my hyperthreads (i7 normally has 8 hyperthreads on older Macbook Pros and 12 on newer ones. So, I chose 6.)
$ minikube --memory 8192 --cpus 6 start

And finally, it's not a bad idea reinstalling minikube if you still have issues:
$ brew cask reinstall minikube

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Docker as a driver, go to Docker Preferences and give it more RAM. The minimum amount is 6GB, the recommended amount is 8GB. I found giving it less than 8 causes this error. Run `minikube delete` and `minikube start` afterwards.